# Como trazer um resultado específico de uma consulta SQL acima dos demais?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` AS `id`, `user_name` AS `name` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

Que gera a saída:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Calebe |
|  2 | João   |
|  3 | Lucas  |
|  4 | Pedro  |
+----+--------+
```

No entanto, preciso que determinado `user` venha nos resultados, antes dos demais. 
**Exemplo**: Quero que o `user_id = 3` apareça no topo. Então o resultado deve vir da seguinte forma:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  3 | Lucas  |
|  1 | Calebe |
|  2 | João   |
|  4 | Pedro  |
+----+--------+
```

Como posso fazê-lo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para a sua query específica, funciona algo desse tipo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` AS `id`, `user_name` AS `name` FROM `users` 
ORDER BY `id` = 3 DESC, `id` ASC;
```

Dessa forma, garante-se que o primeiro termo de ordenação obedece o ID desejado.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` AS `id`, `user_name` AS `name`, if(user_name = `Lucas`,0,1) as `ordem` FROM `users` ORDER BY `ordem` ASC, `id` ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma solução aqui: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823689/how-to-make-sure-a-record-is-always-at-the-top-in-a-given-resultset-in-mysql)

```
ORDER BY (user_id.id=3) ...
```

Comment: Isso vai fazer o ID 3 ficar no final dos resultados. Você precisa usar um `DESC` para colocá-lo no topo.

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode utilizar uma ordem pelo campo e pelos valores desejados, usando a seguinte regra:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` AS `id`, `user_name` AS `name` FROM `users` 
ORDER BY FIELD (id, 3, 1, 2, 4 ) ASC, id DESC;
```